# how to redirect to a page on button click with passing parameters

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, slim-lang

i am using slim template where there is a delete button on clicking it i need to redirect to a page_action of ruby with passing parameters on it
currently i did.  , this is delete button which is redirecting to del_event action of  clevertap_event page

```
          div.column.delete-button-div.col-md-6
        = link_to 'Delete', admin_clevertap_event_del_event_path, :id => "hrlll" , data: {confirm: "Are you sure?" }
```

my action is

```
  page_action :del_event , method: :get do
    id=params[:id]
    puts id
    link_to "Add Event", admin_clevertap_event_add_event_path
  end
```

now i want to get the id that i have passed in html file
can anyone tell how to do that

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation of the `link_to` helper? If you search for `link_to` and `params` you will find good answers.

Comment: okk thanks problem solved i have to give id as  `= link_to 'Delete', admin_clevertap_event_del_event_path(:id = > "testing"),`